# how do I add multiple objectClass attributes using gopkg.in/ldap.v3 ldap.NewAddRequest function?

Tags: go, ldap

In my app I keep default configuration parameters in a toml config file. In the config file I store:

`LdapUserDefaultObjectClass = '"inetOrgPerson","extensibleObject","posixAccount"'`

However, when I use the variable as shown in the code below, the user add transaction fails with:

`RESULT tag=105 err=21 text=objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax`

Visually, the parameter being passed from the toml file and the keyed in string are the same. Is there a requirement that objectClass object be hard coded? out of the few examples I have seen, none of them use a variable for objectClass, but do use variables for other attributes.

Code that fails to add user (Does not work)

```
userAdd := ldap.NewAddRequest("uid=tester007@example,ou=users,dc=example", nil)
userAdd.Attribute("objectClass", []string{ldapClient.LDAP.LdapUserDefaultObjectClas})
// bunch of other attributes that satisfy the object classes below this line
//    ...
ldapConn.Add(userAdd)
```

Error returned:

```
RESULT tag=105 err=21 text=objectClass: value #0 invalid per syntax
```

Code that succeeds adding user (Works!)

```
userAdd := ldap.NewAddRequest("uid=tester007@example,ou=users,dc=example", nil)
userAdd.Attribute("objectClass", []string {"inetOrgPerson","extensibleObject","posixAccount"})
    /// bunch of other attributes that satisfy the object classes below this line
   ...
ldapConn.Add(userAdd)
```

Upon further debugging, I can see that the code that leverages the TOML variables is being parsed differently than when I hard code the literals. I don't fully understand what is happening here and why they are being changed/translated and escaped. I do understand that this is not a TOML issue, but something that is happening when the string is fed to userAdd.Attribute("objectClass", []string {}).

I am new to Go and I have a feeling this is a duh! type issue, but I have tried to convert and quote things in multiple ways and the result is always wrong...

Debug output of failure when using TOML variable

```
Add Request: (Application, Constructed, 0x08) Len=368 "<nil>"
  DN: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=39 "uid=tester007@example,ou=users,dc=example"
  Attributes: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=323 "<nil>"
   Attribute: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=66 "<nil>"
    Type: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=11 "objectClass"
    AttributeValue: (Universal, Constructed, Set and Set OF) Len=51 "<nil>"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=49 "\"inetOrgPerson\",\"extensibleObject\",\"posixAccount\""
```

Debug output showing successful add. This is when the values are hard coded.

```
Add Request: (Application, Constructed, 0x08) Len=364 "<nil>"
DN: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=39 "uid=tester007@example,ou=users,dc=example"
  Attributes: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=319 "<nil>"
   Attribute: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=62 "<nil>"
    Type: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=11 "objectClass"
    AttributeValue: (Universal, Constructed, Set and Set OF) Len=47 "<nil>"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=13 "inetOrgPerson"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=16 "extensibleObject"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=12 "posixAccount"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out (n00b).

the TOML definition was fine. The problem was on how I was trying to populate the objectClass attribute. I was trying to pass a `string` into a `[]string` (string struct?). What I did not understand was that I could pass my own `[]string` to the function.

basically I did not understand that `[]string{}` could be replace with my own `[]string` variable:

wrong:

`userAdd.Attribute("objectClass", []string{ldapClient.LDAP.LdapUserDefaultObjectClass})`

**correct:**

- assign ldapClient.LDAP.LdapUserDefaultObjectClass to objClass - nice not needed

`objClass := ldapClient.LDAP.LdapUserDefaultObjectClass`

- Split objClass into slices

`userObjectClasses := (strings.Split(objClass, ","))`

- Use userObjectClasses to pass AttVals.

`userAdd.Attribute("objectClass", userObjectClasses)`

Debug output:

```
 Add Request: (Application, Constructed, 0x08) Len=364 "<nil>"
  DN: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=39 "uid=tester007@example,ou=users,dc=example"
  Attributes: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=319 "<nil>"
   Attribute: (Universal, Constructed, Sequence and Sequence of) Len=62 "<nil>"
    Type: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=11 "objectClass"
    AttributeValue: (Universal, Constructed, Set and Set OF) Len=47 "<nil>"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=13 "inetOrgPerson"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=16 "extensibleObject"
     Vals: (Universal, Primitive, Octet String) Len=12 "posixAccount"
```

I hope that this can help someone else learning Go and the LDAP package.

- sanity saver: https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Split
- helpful: https://medium.com/golangspec/composite-literals-in-go-10dc62eec06a